# Is Pivotal Cloud Foundry dead?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, paas

Today I created a PCF Account (for testing purposes) and it will not let me do anything , it is telling me this:

"We will no longer be accepting any new PWS account sign-ups after September 17, 2020.

Please do not hesitate to contact us with any questions. If you are interested in an enterprise-grade service for hosting applications, Tanzu Application Service (TAS) offers this capability.

The VMware Team"

Does this mean that I need to move my production applications from PCF to VMware Tanzu ? Is PCF Dead?

Answer (score 1):

Pivotal Web Services is not the same as Pivotal Cloud Foundry. Pivotal Web Services has been sunset, yes. Tanzu Application Service is VMware's enterprise solution that is, if you want to think about it this way, a self-hosted Pivotal Web Services (this is a gross understatement, but works for this situation). Are you looking to test Cloud Foundry for its suitability?

Comment: PWS is just one hosted provider. There are others. The Cloud Foundry foundation maintains a list of them here -> https://www.cloudfoundry.org/certified-platforms/. If you are looking for something similar to PWS that you don't need to host, that is a good place to start.